# Exception in data insertion

Tags: java, jdbc

```
        String Name=request.getParameter("Name");
         String Email=request.getParameter("Email");
          String Password=request.getParameter("Password");
           String Contact=request.getParameter("Contact");
            Connection con=rcplconnect.con;
             PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement("insert into 
     register(email,name,pass,phone) values(?,?,?,?)");
            pst.setString(1,Name);
            pst.setString(2,Email);
            pst.setString(3,Password);
            pst.setString(4,Contact);



                    int i=pst.executeUpdate();
```

I am trying to insert data from my signup page but it is getting exception every time. Could anyone tell me what the exception is and how to remove it?

Comment: can you post your exception?

Comment: You're in a much better position to answer your question than we are.  Are the parameters all set to non NULL values?  Does your database connection work?  Did you try looking at the exception, assuming one is being thrown by your update code?

Comment: Please post your exception

Comment: Is it like a puzzle? Shall we guess what exception do you get? Can you please update your question with more info and paste exception here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have a `ServletException` and an `IOException`. An IOException is just that, an input or output exception. When people use them, they are normally just generalizing a more specific error. The API has a list of all the different types of IO exceptions that are built into Java.

Here are some cases which result in `IOException`.

- Reading from a closed inputstream
- Try to access a file on the internet without a net connection

If there is any error with status code either 404 ( Not Found) or 403 ( Forbidden ) then the ServletException may be thrown